# Why does Sencha 2 only work in Webkit browsers?

Tags: sencha-touch-2

What does Sencha 2 only work in Webkit browsers? I understand they require the Webkit engine, but why do they do this, what does this webkit engine have which the engines in Firefox / IE doesnt have? A browser consists of a HTML engine, CSS engine and Javascript engine - just for curriosity, is it the Javascript engine which is special with Webkit in respect of Sencha ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When Sencha Touch started development, iphone, android and blackberry were the main platforms. All of them use a webkit based browser as default.

There were reasons told at that time like css transistions and image masking weren't supported by other browsers. I guess things might have improved now.

Size is also an issue. To support more browsers, more workarounds are required which increase the size of the framework.

From a business perspective, there isn't really a demand for supporting any other browser. If ie10 becomes big with Windows 8, they might support it as people have already asked about it their forums.

Someones already trying to make it work on Firfox. Here is the [link](https://github.com/martin1982/senchafox).
Here are some posts from the forum
[Post1](http://www.sencha.com/forum/showthread.php?149067-Sencha-touch-on-windows-phone-Mango&highlight=mozilla), [Post2](http://www.sencha.com/forum/showthread.php?146925-Basic-Sencha-Touch-Mozilla&highlight=mozilla)

Comment: thanks for reply, so its the CSS engine which cause them not to support other than Webkit browsers for now